# I have a google ads script that should return all campaigns, but it doesn't

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting, ads

I'm trying to write a google ads script that'll change budgets accourding to some rules. However, at first, I tried to get all campaigns using CampaignIterator. However, only 1 campaign is fetched although there're many campaigns in the account.

```
function main() {
    var currentAccount = AdsApp.currentAccount();
  Logger.log('Customer ID: ' + currentAccount.getCustomerId() +
      ', Currency Code: ' + currentAccount.getCurrencyCode() +
      ', Timezone: ' + currentAccount.getTimeZone());
  var stats = currentAccount.getStatsFor('YESTERDAY');
  Logger.log(stats.getClicks() + ' clicks, ' +
    stats.getImpressions() + ' impressions last month');

  var campaignIterator = AdsApp.campaigns()
      .get();
     Logger.log('Total campaigns found : ' +
      campaignIterator.totalNumEntities());
}
```

The upper part of the script brings the true clicks&impressions data, however, the below part, campaign iterator part only returns one campaign. I already tried to use with  .next method however it always brings only one campaign.